# How do you create a while true loop while still keeping a tkinter page open?

Tags: loops, tkinter, python-3.7

I am trying to create a tkinter page that shows the time and it should be constantly updated. I have tried:

```
from tkinter.font import *
import time
def SetTime():
    global time_date
    time_date = time.strftime("%H:%M")
    InfoTime.set(time_date)
Main = Tk()
Main.geometry("1600x1200")
Main.title("Time")
FontStyle = Font(family = "Times New Roman", size = 48)
InfoTime = StringVar()
TitleText = Label(Main,textvariable = InfoTime,font = FontStyle).pack()
while True:
    SetTime()
```

However, running the 
`While True:` line and running
`SetTime()`
constantly is for some reason preventing the tkinter page (Main) from opening. This has been a problem for a lot of my tkinter projects.

Please note, I am running python 3.7.2 in IDLE.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import *
import time

Main = Tk()
Main.geometry("1600x1200")
Main.title("Time")

FontStyle = Font(family = "Times New Roman", size = 48)
TitleText = Label(Main, font = FontStyle)
TitleText.pack()

time_date1 = ''

def SetTime():
    global time_date1
    global TitleText

    # Gets current time
    time_date2 = time.strftime("%H:%M")
    # If time has changed, update it
    if time_date2 != time_date1:
        time_date1 = time_date2
        TitleText.config(text=time_date2)

    # Repeats function every 200 milliseconds 
    TitleText.after(200, SetTime)

SetTime()
Main.mainloop()
```

The comments pretty much explain everything. I also cleaned up and reformatted your code to make it look nicer.